# client side callback is not working in dash plotly

Tags: javascript, callback, plotly-dash

Hi i am trying get input using prompt in JS and that input is later passed into regular callbacks which is then printed in the screen, this is my dash code and custom-script.js code

dash.py:

```
import dash
import dash_table
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input,Output,State,ClientsideFunction



app=dash.Dash()
server = app.server
app.layout=html.Div([
    dcc.Store(id='error',data={}),
    html.Div(id='output')
])

app.clientside_callback(
    ClientsideFunction(
        namespace='clientside',
        function_name='error_text'
    ),
    
    Output('error','data')
)

@app.callback(Output('output','children'),
              [Input('error','data')])
def error_text(error):
    return error
    
       
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

assets/custom-script.js:

```
window.dash_clientside = Object.assign({}, window.dash_clientside, {
    clientside: {
        error_text: function() {
            var error=prompt('enter the error text');
            if(error!==null){
            return {errorText:error};
            }
        }
    }
});
```

when i run my dash app, prompt ie client side script is not at all working and i am getting a error for regular callback like input for callback is none, kindly help me out

error message:
**
In the callback for output(s):
error.data
there are no `Input` elements.
Without `Input` elements, it will never get called.

Subscribing to `Input` components will cause the
callback to be called whenever their values change.
**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, as the error says, that your `clientside_callback` doesn't have an `Input`. Just like regular Dash callbacks, clientside callbacks also need to have at least one `Input` and one `Output`:

```
app.clientside_callback(
    ClientsideFunction(namespace="clientside", function_name="error_text"),
    Output("error", "data"),
    Input("error", "data"),
)
```

The above would work on page load since dash runs callbacks on start of the app if not specified otherwise.

Now you might want to have a different input / trigger than the example above shows, but you need to have at least one `Input`.

---

Aditionally you can't return an object in your `error_text` function since your `error_text` callback outputs to `children` which doesn't accept objects.

In this case you could just return the error text as is:

```
window.dash_clientside = Object.assign({}, window.dash_clientside, {
  clientside: {
    error_text: function () {
      var error = prompt("enter the error text");
      if (error !== null) {
        return error
      }
    },
  },
});
```